# how to add role to user from an array1?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a user from an array, how can I give him a role?

My code:

```js
if (interaction.customId == "buttoninvyes" + (i+1)) {
  const channelinv = "1173243142032609340"
  console.log(applicationList[i].id)
  client.channels.cache.get(channelinv).send(`${applicationList[i]}`);
  applicationList.split(i,1);
}}
})

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
    return;
  }
  applicationList.push(interaction.user)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In `discord.js`, you can add roles to a guild member using the following code:

```js
<guildMember>.roles.add(roleId);
```

Full example:

```js
if (interaction.customId == "buttoninvyes" + (i+1)) {
  const channelinv = "1173243142032609340"
  console.log(applicationList[i].id)
  client.channels.cache.get(channelinv).send(`${applicationList[i]}`);
  // Change this line
  applicationList.splice(I, 1);

  const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(applicationList[i].id);

  // Add the role to the member
  member.roles.add(roleId).catch(console.error);
}
```